# Blazor - How to set value from childcontent property

Tags: blazor

How to set value from childcontent property

index.razor

```
  <ButtonName>Submit</ButtonName>
```

ButtonName.razor

```
<input type="radio" value=@childContent>
<label> @childContent </label>
```

Comment: Would you mind marking it as the answer if it solved your problem, so others know it was useful.

Comment: If any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. If there's still anything unclear in the given answers, don't hesitate to ask by using the comment function under the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should define a parameter property named ChildContent in ButtonName.razor, like this:

```
[Parameter]
 public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
```

And use it like this:

```
<input type="radio" value=@ChildContent>
<label> @ChildContent </label>
```

Note that ChildContent contains initial capital letter C